# Opening Visualforce page from Lightning Component, not showing header with back button on mobile app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile, url, navigation

In our org, we have a lightning component that opens a Visualforce page.  On mobile, we want the mobile header that contains a back button to be visible, or for a header with a "Close" button to be visible in order to navigate back to the Saleforce page we were on from the Visualforce page.

However, the Visualforce page is opening with no header, and the user gets stuck on the Visualforce page. We discovered this issue after Summer 19 release.

This is the code we have been using:

`var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
urlEvent.setParams({
    "url": "/apex/PageName?c__sfdc.tabName=01r5500000009QE#/opportunity/"
});
urlEvent.fire();`

We tried with and without the "c__" before the "sfdc".

I also tried with a navService (including `<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>` in the component) and a page reference, but the same behavior was hapenning:

`var pageReference = {
   "type": "standard__webPage",
   "attributes": {
         "url": "/apex/PageName?c__sfdc.tabName=01r5500000009QE#/opportunity/"
    }
};
var navService = component.find("navService");
navService.navigate(pageReference, false);`

Also tried with the `sforce.one` library, but sforce is undefined, my understanding is because this code is in a lightning component, not a Visualforce page.

Am I wrong for assuming that the header should automatically appear on the Visualforce page?  Does anyone know if there is a more proper way to be doing this or if I am missing and parameters?

Attaching two pictures of the tops of the mobile app, one with the back button (which we want) and one of the Visualforce page, without the back button.

What we want on top:
[image: Desired header]

What we are getting on top:
[image: Missing header]

Thanks.